# How to resolve type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, flutter

I am trying to fetch user data but getting below error while doing so:

```
Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>
```

I looked at various solutions for similar issue and changed my code accordingly (ex: used `<String, dynamic>` instead of `<dynamic, dynamic>`, but still am seeing this error.

Model snippet:

```
// Returns a Pro created from JSON
  factory Pro.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    Pro pro = Pro();

    pro.uid = json['uid'];
    pro.email = json['email'];
```

And fetching this data as below and calling this method in `initState()`:

```
Future<Pro> _getPro() async {
    await userDatabaseReference.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      Map<String, dynamic> values = snapshot.value;
      values["uid"] = snapshot.key;
      print(snapshot.key); 
      Pro fetchedUser = Pro.fromJson(values);
      setState(() {
        this.pro = fetchedUser;
      });
    });
  }
```

If I use `Map<String, dynamic> values`, then I get error at same line and if I use `Map<dynamic, dynamic> values`, then I get error at:
`Pro fetchedUser = Pro.fromJson(values)`

Since, `Pro.fromJson(values)` has parameter type `Map<String, dynamic>` which is the same parameter type I used to declare `values` but still not sure why its throwing the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try as below where we convert values first into Map.from() and then use that with fromJson method of Pro model:

```
Future<Pro> _getPro() async {
    await userDatabaseReference.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      Map<String, dynamic> values = snapshot.value;
      values["uid"] = snapshot.key;
      print(snapshot.key); 
      final mapJsonCategory = Map<String, dynamic>.from(values);
      Pro fetchedUser = Pro.fromJson(mapJsonCategory);
      setState(() {
        this.pro = fetchedUser;
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Awesome..great to know that we first need to convert values into Map.from() and that's where I was stuck.